# Failure: (ID: 838926df) did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

when running `gcloud app deploy` on my spring boot app, this error happens in Cloud Build.

Comment: I am getting same error while deploying through jenkins. I have mentioned springframework.boot plugin still i am getting below error:`Error ID: 838926df
Error type: UNKNOWN
Error message: did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted my maven plugin by accident, so don't delete it.

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

There can be one or many issues because of which you get this error.
For resolution please check below things -

1. Your `app.yaml` should have entrypoint and runtime information as below -

   `runtime: java11`
   `entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar blahblah.jar`
2. your `pom.xml` should have appengine maven plugin dependency

`

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>    
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

`

3. don't modify jar if you want to replace any configs use command -
   `jar uf blahblah.jar filename.yaml`
4. make sure you have packaging as a jar in `pom.xml` like this -
   `<packaging>jar</packaging>`

Comment: This is good. I also realized I was in a subdirectory when I kept using the command: gcloud app deploy. I had initially done that to deploy a new cron.yaml file which for some reason was not being deployed from the root project dir. Later, I forgot I was in that dir and I was making changes to pom.xml but it kept saying 0 files uploaded. When I came back to the parent, it worked! Just a tip that be mindful of the dir location of where you are running your gcloud commands from.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it for my AppEngine + Gradle project by adding

```
jar {
    enabled = false
    archiveClassifier = ''
}
```

to the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out in pom.xml packaging into war file, example:

```
<!--  <packaging>war</packaging> -->
```

It fixed the issue for me. Good minimal+workable example is here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot#0

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the fact that the packaged `.jar` file does not have a `Main-Class` entry in `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

My original `MANIFEST.MF` file looked like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.8.6
Built-By: me
Build-Jdk: 19.0.1
```

For me, the solution was to add the `maven-jar-plugin` and manually configure the `mainClass`.

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>my.main.MainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This resulted in the following `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 19
Main-Class: my.main.MainClass
```

You could also check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class for other options, but then you'll have to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent...