# App engine "Non zero exit: 1" error when application deploy

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, pom.xml, app.yaml

I am trying to deploy a new version of the application on the google app engine but I am getting this error:

```
com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
```

I am clon the repo from git and trying to deploy the application with the command: **"gcloud app deploy"**
on the location of file app.yaml (Should be configured correctly).

I also try to deploy aplicatony b mvn by command: **"mvn package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=projektID"**

But it will give me the same error.

It is already an existing application so I don't have to create a new app or should I? Can you please help me or at least give me some advice?

**Full stack trace:**

```
     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project demo: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        -> [Help 1]
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project demo: App Engine application deployment failed
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
                at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
                at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
                at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
                at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
                at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
                at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
                at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
                at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
            Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: App Engine application deployment failed
                at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy (AppDeployer.java:59)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:35)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.Deployment.deploy (Deployment.java:98)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy (AppDeployer.java:57)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:35)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.handleProcess (LegacyProcessHandler.java:87)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.GcloudRunner.run (GcloudRunner.java:110)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.Deployment.deploy (Deployment.java:96)at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy (AppDeployer.java:57)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit (NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:28)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.syncRun (LegacyProcessHandler.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.handleProcess (LegacyProcessHandler.java:83)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.GcloudRunner.run (GcloudRunner.java:110)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.Deployment.deploy (Deployment.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy (AppDeployer.java:57)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
```

Comment: Does your pom.xml and app.yaml has the matching Java runtime version? Please check this thread similar to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264254/appengine-maven-plugin1-3-1-run-failed-non-zero-exit

Comment: My problem was actually in the wrong logger implementation.

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem. But how did you do that? how did you diagnose the problem? How did you determine that it was the logger, from the error message "deployment failed" and "Non zero exit: 1" ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out more as to why the error occured, run `mvn appengine:deploy -e -X` (-X to log debugging info, -e to log stack trace).

In my case, I ran into multiple issues. The first one was easy to figure out:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not currently have an active account selected.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Please run:
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD:   $ gcloud auth login
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: to obtain new credentials.
```

On the next run, I got:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build ... status: FAILURE
[INFO] GCLOUD: did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry
[INFO] GCLOUD: Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=europe-west1/...?project=...
```

Checking the build logs:

```
Step #2 - "build": Failure: (ID: 838926df) did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry
Step #2 - "build": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #2 - "build": Running "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-6393296178649966364 /builder/outputs/output"
Step #2 - "build": Done "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-6393296178649966364 /builder/o..." (46.762072ms)
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/java/builder:java_20230320_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 51
```

Leading to [Failure: (ID: 838926df) did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158436/failure-id-838926df-did-not-find-any-jar-files-with-a-main-class-manifest-en)

My point being: in order to troubleshoot, add  `-X` to the deploy command which will usually give you some extra clues as to what exactly is going wrong.